# Data not populating in Vue app

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get some data from my vuex store into a component via `computed`. For some reason, it's not letting me access `userInfo.uid` in a couple of my components. It's saying that `userInfo.uid` is `undefined` even though VueTools is clearly showing that it has been successfully imported. Not sure why this is happening. For example here is a quiz component where I try to get the `userInfo` data from my vuex store so I can use it to access some data at a firebase reference.

Shouldn't I be able to access my vuex state using `this.$store.state`? It's throwing an error when I do that as well. Anyway, the following code gives me undefined 95% of the time. Except randomly it will give the `userId` then I reload the page and it's back to `undefined`. No idea what's going on. Thanks!

Quiz.vue

```
<template>

</template>

<script>

// TODO: WHY IS userInfo.uid UNDEFINED!!!!?????

var db = firebase.database();
import store from '../store'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import VueFire from 'vuefire'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(VueFire)

export default {
    name: 'quiz',
    computed: mapState({
        userInfo: state => state.userInfo
    }),
    created () {
        console.log(store.state.userInfo.uid)
    },
    components: {},
    firebase: {
        quiz: db.ref('/users/' + store.state.userInfo.uid + '/createdResources/' + store.state.postKey + '/quiz/')
    }
}
</script>

<style>
    .quiz {
        margin-top: 60px;
        padding: 40px;
        width: 800px;
        background-color: white
    }
<style>
```

Comment: In your picture there's **apiKey**, is it ok to show it to everyone?

Comment: Haven't used firebase myself. Does `db` fetch data from the server or from something like local-storage?

Comment: Fetches data from a backend-as-a-service. The issue seems to be the `userInfo` being undefined in `createdResources.vue` but I have no idea why it's showing up `undefined`. I pass in `props: [userInfo]` to `createdResources.vue` which should allow me access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lifecycle hook: [updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated)

> Called after a data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered and patched.
>
> The component’s DOM will be in updated state when this hook is called, so you can perform DOM-dependent operations in this hook. However, in most cases you should avoid changing state in this hook, because it may lead to an infinite update loop.
>
> This hook is not called during server-side rendering.

You can refer to following lifecycle diagram on what event will called when.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `computed` instead of `created` in `CreatedResources`, just like in the parent component. EDIT: Since we have to use vuefire's `$bindAsArray`, which makes it hard to declare `createdResources` as `computed`, `watch` `userInfo` and put what's inside `created` there.

explanation:

`created` is invoked only once in a component's lifetime, while `computed` re-evals every time its involved component properties change (and since vuex suggest use computed too, computed must also detects state changes). Also try putting the `log` in `computed` in the parent component, it should log the value when `userInfo` state changes.

As the [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) explains, `computed` watches properties changes, which can also be achived with `watch`, with one thing superior: it caches the computed values until the dependencies change, while `watch` evals every time you ask for the computed value.

optional improvement:

Putting `db...` in the parent and pass the server-side-fetched data to the child would be better since the child serves as a generic displayer and should receive ready-to-display-in-view data. (it has no idea what the data means, but only cares if the data matches its predefined structure)

Comment: What do you suggest I put in `computed` in `CreatedResources`? I thought computed only took functions pretty much? If I'm getting the data in via props why would I need a computed property as well?

Comment: @staxwell edited. You have props passed in but still need `db` to fetch something more with `userInfo.uid`, am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I need `db` to fetch something from firebase who's path is the `db.ref('/users/' + userInfo.uid + '/createdResources/')`

Comment: It seems like when I import data from vuex using `computed` it's just not letting me access it from within the component. No idea why this is.

Comment: @staxwell update the question to show what we have currently?

Comment: I've updated it with a simpler component. It's giving me the same issue.